# binary to char in C?

Tags: c

I have an array

```
bin =

     0     1     1     0     0     0     0     1
     0     1     1     0     0     1     0     1
     0     1     1     1     0     0     1     0
     0     1     1     1     0     0     1     1
     0     1     1     0     0     1     1     1
     0     1     1     0     1     0     1     0
     0     1     1     0     1     0     0     0
     0     1     1     0     0     0     0     1
     0     1     1     1     0     1     0     0
     0     0     1     0     0     1     1     1
     0     1     0     0     1     0     1     0
     0     1     0     0     1     0     0     0
```

> Every line in the array is a 8 bits binary letter

bin is equivalent to this string `aersgjhat'JH`

This is very simple using matlab, but I couldn't find how to convert a table full of binary 8 bit words to a string in C.

Comment: what's exactly `erray`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions here. Please be aware that we do not provide _from-scratch_ coding service. Please show us what you've tried already, how it failed and we might be able to help.:-)

Comment: Also, read about [Positional notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positional_notation)

Comment: You should probably learn the basics of the C language.

Comment: @MichaelWalz ok, Why's so?

Comment: array = table= tableau

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unimportant what is the type of the `bin`. It may be some integer type. For the demonstrative purpose I used type `uint8_t`. You can use for example type `int`.

The program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main( void )
{
    uint8_t bin[][8] =
    {    
        { 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
        { 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1 },
        { 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0 },
        { 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1 },
        { 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1 },
        { 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0 },
        { 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
        { 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1 },
        { 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0 },
        { 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 },
    };

    const size_t N = sizeof( bin ) / sizeof( *bin ); 
    char s[N + 1] = { '\0' };

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < 8; j++  )
        {
            s[i] = ( ( unsigned char )s[i] << 1 ) | ( bin[i][j] & 1 );
        }
    }

    puts( s );
}
```

The program output is

```
aersgjhat'JH
```

Answer (score 0):

You really need to read in each byte of the array - I'm assuming a '0' is no bit set and '1' is bit set ...

A loop that sets each bit would probably do the job - if I'm reading your array correctly ....

```
unsigned char bin[] = {....}   // your array full of data
unsigned char output[ 16 ]      // you will need to set the output size...
int nIndex = 0;
int nOutIndex = 0;
....

// the inner loop ...
output[ nOutIndex ] = 0;
for( nIndex = 0; nIndex < 8; nIndex++ )
{
    if ( bin[ nIndex ] == 1 )
       output[ nOutIndex ] |= 1;

    output[ nOutIndex ] <<= 1;
}
```

This example shows a simple method for setting the bit and shifting. Please note this is only the inner loop, and there's no code for moving through the bin array (from the second char onwards.

Answer (score 0):

Get a `value_so_far` initialized to `0`

```
int value_so_far = 0;
```

Read a bit, multiply the `value_so_far` by `2` and add that bit

```
int bit;
if (scanf("%d", &bit) != 1) /* error */;
if (bit < 0 || bit > 1) /* error */;
value_so_far *= 2;
value_so_far += bit;
```

After 8 times, you have an 8-bit value.
Restart.